# How do I resolve DNSvalidation error on Heroku

Tags: laravel, validation, email, heroku

Using Laravel validator, I tried to validate email using the email validator format like this

```
'email' => 'required|email:dns'
```

It's working locally after editing my php.ini file but when hosted on heroku it throws some error. Here is the error message

`The Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\DNSCheckValidation class requires the Intl extension.`

Please how do I resolve this?

Comment: You install the intl extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi you need to enable the intl extension by editing the php.ini file if you use xampp you can find it inside the c://Xampp/php/
search for intl and you may get 
;extension=intl
just remove the semicolon and everything works fine


see more here
```